# SSH library for java which very well supports mutithreading!

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm searching for a library that would allow me to create lets say 3 threads for remote command execution each command to execute takes ~13 min. What ssh lib for java would you suggest, which would be able to perform such a task? (free Maveric version - failed not willing to pay 2.4k$ for full library, now fighting using ssh2...)

Comment: Why not use any SSH lib combined with `Executor`/`ExecutorService`?

Comment: @musiKk, not all SSH libraries have been written in a threadsafe manner. JSch apparently has this problem as of today (unless this has changed) if one goes through their mailing list.

Comment: @Vineet: Sorry, maybe I did not sufficiently check my facts. Alas, WhiteFang34 seems to disagree. ;)

Comment: but executors only ececute each command at the time? I mean execute 1com , 2com, 3 com... not all at once

Comment: @user615927: Not if you use e.g. a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a pool size of >1.

Answer (score 4):

I know from personal experience that [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) works fine for this as long as you create a separate SSH connection for each thread. There's also [sshj](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/) and [Ganymed SSH-2](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/) that you might want to check out.

Here's a quick example of remote command execution with JSch:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();

Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect(timeout);

Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) channel;
channelExec.setCommand(command);
channel.connect();

// read channel.getInputStream() here if you want to capture the output

channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

Comment: +1, the nature of SSH doesn't "multithread" naturally. It's a stream of commands, and streams are serial by nature.

Comment: The only problem I had with Jsch is that it has no ducumentation(3 times longer than ssh2==GANYMED SSH-2)-> leads to not beeing able to strat SHELL commenction without stupid input streams i mean start.shell(); execute.command(String); execute.command(String); end.shell(); but probably you solvesd this mistery(I think I've seen something about shell multiple commands(in application No reading from keyboard) in one of your posts)

Comment: I updated the answer with a working example, you just need to fill in the variables.

Comment: thanks for your help, but my friend honor the SHELL, SHELL loads .profile and all specific scrips in server , exec connection doesnt do that , if i'd use exec i'd have to load the paths to scripts and thats pain, i need shell type connection! by the way it was not ssh lib fault but the servers he wasn't able to excecute multiple commands at same time

Comment: Ah, yeah I actually use it with `session.openChannel("shell")` for my cases. It is more involved to manage, however it does load the profile as desired. Other libraries might make this easier, however I don't have experience with them to provide any advice or examples.